# Is there any way to import a full bootstrap template into a ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Attempting to download a bootstrap template from here (http://startbootstrap.com/) and put it in a Ruby on rails project locally and begin to edit from there?

Comment: Doesn't it work? Where it fails? Do you have an example?

Comment: @kwoxer there are issue with image imports and the styles, for example background color isn't working. however, all are working in a plain editor.

Answer (score 0):

With your downloaded bootstrap.

1. Copy:
   bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css and bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
   To: vendor/assets/stylesheets
2. Copy:
   bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js and bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
   To: vendor/assets/javascripts
3. Update: app/assets/stylesheets/application.css by adding:
   *= require bootstrap.min
4. Update: app/assets/javascripts/application.jsby adding:
   //= require bootstrap.min

Comment: Should I put it in the .keep file?

Comment: No need to put it in the `.keep` file. Did it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Bootstarp gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)  for this. And require the bootstrap css and js files in you application.css and application.js.